# Custumize Node Template and Edge Template using NGX-GRAPH not works

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-graph

I'm new to NGX-GRAPH. I'm trying to build an oriented graph.
This is my code:

**ngx-graph.component.html**:

```
<ngx-graph *ngIf="nodes?.length > 0 && links?.length > 0"
          [links]="links"
          [nodes]="nodes"></ngx-graph>
```

**ngx-graph.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from '../server.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Edge, Node} from '@swimlane/ngx-graph';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ngx-graph',
  templateUrl: './ngx-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ngx-graph.component.scss']
})
export class NgxGraphComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  nodes: Node[] = [];
  links: Edge[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.serverService.getGraphGivenEndpointId(this.id).subscribe(
      response => { this.nodes = response[0];
                    this.links = response[1];
                    console.log(this.nodes);

      }
    );
  }
}
```

This is my **JSON returned by a service**:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "first", label: "A", meta: {…}, dimension: {…}, position: {…}, …}
1: {id: "second", label: "B", meta: {…}, dimension: {…}, position: {…}, …}
2: {id: "first", label: "A", meta: {…}, dimension: {…}, position: {…}, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**ServerService.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private elencoEndpointService: ElencoEndpointService) {}

    getGraphGivenEndpointId(id: number) {
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/app/endpoint?id=' + id);
    }
}
```

With this code, the library works fine. I obtain the basic graph, like the one in the "quickstart" page https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/#/#outputs.

But if I try to customize the nodes adding only this part without changing anything else:

```
<ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
        <svg:g class="node">
            <svg:rect [attr.width]="node.dimension.width" [attr.height]="node.dimension.height"
                [attr.fill]="node.data.color" />
            <svg:text alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="10" [attr.y]="node.dimension.height / 2">{{node.label}}
            </svg:text>
        </svg:g>
    </ng-template>
```

My **ngx-graph.component.html** becomes:

```
        <ngx-graph *ngIf="nodes?.length > 0 && links?.length > 0"
          [links]="links"
          [nodes]="nodes"
        >
        <ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
          <svg:g class="node">
            <svg:rect [attr.width]="node.dimension.width" [attr.height]="node.dimension.height"
              [attr.fill]="node.data.color" />
            <svg:text alignment-baseline="central" [attr.x]="10" [attr.y]="node.dimension.height / 2">{{node.label}}
            </svg:text>
          </svg:g>
        </ng-template>
        </ngx-graph>
```

**the nodes in the graph disappear and the edge are still displayed but without nodes**. I get **no error** in console or in angular.

I also added this code to my ngx-graph.component.ts, to trigger an update but nothing changed:

```
this.nodes.forEach(element => {
                      this.nodes.push(element);
                      this.nodes = [...this.nodes];
                    });
```

This is my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes, Router} from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { AddEndpointComponent } from './add-endpoint/add-endpoint.component';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { ElencoEndpointComponent } from './elenco-endpoint/elenco-endpoint.component';
import { ElencoEndpointService } from './elencoEndpoint.service';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServerService } from './server.service';
import { NgxGraphModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-graph';
import { NgxGraphComponent } from './ngx-graph/ngx-graph.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {TextFieldModule} from '@angular/cdk/text-field';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomePageComponent},
  {path: 'add-endpoint', component: AddEndpointComponent},
  {path: 'view-endpoint', component: ElencoEndpointComponent},
  {path: 'view-endpoint/:id', component: NgxGraphComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    AddEndpointComponent,
    ElencoEndpointComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    NgxGraphComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    NgxGraphModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    A11yModule,
    TextFieldModule,
  ],
  providers: [ElencoEndpointService, ServerService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have follow this:

> Quick Start
>   Install the package: npm install @swimlane/ngx-graph --save
>
> Import NgxGraphModule into your angular module
>
> Add the ngx-graph component

What is the problem?

Maybe I have to import something else that is not specify in the quickstart page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For these cases knowing the versions of the packages you use helps immensely. I suggest adding the lines for your angular as well as ngx-graph from your package.json to your question.

Answer (score 1):

ngx-graph 6.2.0 is incompatible with Angular 9.

NPM or Yarn should give you a missing peer dependency warning.

Installing the next version of ngx-graph (7.0.0-rc.1 and not 6.2.0) will help. I guess angular 9.0.3 is compatible only with the version 7.0.0-rc.1.

Use one of the following commands:

`yarn add @swimlane/ngx-graph@next`

`npm i @swimlane/ngx-graph@next`